# Why __str__(self) doesn't work when calling the print() function?

Tags: python, string, oop

I'm diving into OOP and learning magic (or dunder) techniques. Python 3.8.8.

I created class FreqStack() with a pop() method that removes the most frequent elements and returns an updated stack.

```
class FreqStack():

def __init__(self, lst:list = None):
    if lst is None:
        self.stack = []
    else:
        self.stack = lst[::-1]

def push(self, el: int):
    self.stack.insert(0, el)
    return self.stack

def pop(self):
    if len(self.stack) != 0:
        hash_map = {}
        for el in self.stack:
            hash_map[el] = hash_map.get(el, 0) + 1
        most_freq_el = max(hash_map, key=hash_map.get)

        while most_freq_el in self.stack: 
            self.stack.remove(most_freq_el)
        
        return self.stack 
    else:
        return 'Stack is empty!'
    
def __str__(self):
    return '\n|\n'.join(str(el) for el in self.stack)
```

I also added the dunder method **str**(), which, as far as I understand correctly, must return a custom string when calling the print() function.
However, the print() function in the example below, instead of returning a string, returns a list.

```
lst = [1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 9]
freq_stack = FreqStack(lst)

for i in range(6):
    print(freq_stack.pop())

Output:
[9, 7, 7, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1]
[9, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1]
[9, 7, 7]
[9]
[]
Stack is empty!
```

I googled everything related to this problem, and couldn't solve it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You never call print on your FreqStack object.

Comment: Also, print function does not return list. Nor a string. It doesn't return anything, for that matter. It outputs some characters to stdout.

Comment: Instead of *return self.stack* you could *return str(self)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the return value of `pop`, not the `freq_stack` itself.
The `__str__` method is for the `freq_stack` object, so you may try something like:

```
freq_stack.pop()
print(freq_stack)
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation:)